# Can Caffe or Caffe2 be given input data directly from gpu?

Tags: python, c++, caffe, caffe2

I've read caffe2 tutorials and tried pre-trained models. I knew caffe2 will leverge GPU to run the model/net. But the input data seems always be given from CPU(ie. Host) memory. For example, in [Loading Pre-Trained Models](https://caffe2.ai/docs/tutorial-loading-pre-trained-models.html), after model is loaded, we can predict an image by

```
result = p.run([img])
```

However, image "img" should be read in CPU scope. What I look for is a framework that can pipline the images (which is decoded from a video and still resides in GPU memory) directly to the prediction model, instead of copying it from GPU to CPU scope, and then transfering to GPU again to predict result. Is Caffe or Caffe2 provides such functions or interfaces for python or C++? Or should I need to patch Caffe to do so? Thanks at all.

---

Here is my solution:

I'd found in `tensor.h`, function `ShareExternalPointer()` can exactly do what I want.

Feed gpu data this way,

```
pInputTensor->ShareExternalPointer(pGpuInput, InputSize);
```

then run the predict net through

```
pPredictNet->Run();
```

where `pInputTensor` is the entrance tensor for the predict net `pPredictNet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in [caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe) with python interface.
But I think that it can be accomplished using the c++: In c++ you have access to the `Blob`'s `mutable_gpu_data()`. You may write code that run on device and "fill" the input Blob's `mutable_gpu_data()` directly from gpu. Once you made this update, caffe should be able to continue its `net->forward()` from there.

**UPDATE**
On Sep 19th, 2017 [PR #5904](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5904) was merged into master. This PR exposes GPU pointers of blobs via the python interface.
You may access `blob._gpu_data_ptr` and `blob._gpu_diff_ptr` directly from python **at your own risk**.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, using a Python layer forces data in and out of the GPU, and this can cause a huge hit to performance. This is true not just for Caffe, but for other frameworks too. To elaborate on Shai's answer, you could look at [this step-by-step tutorial on adding C++ layers to Caffe](http://ai.terrawx.com/new-layer.html). The example given should touch on most issues dealing with layer implementation. Disclosure: I am the author.